# Zend framework maxlength validation with HtmlEntities filter

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi i am using ZF1 and have one problem. Here is my form

```
  $htmlEntities = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities(array(
      'doublequote'  => false,
      'quotestyle'   => ENT_NOQUOTES /*| ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML5*/
    ));
    $elements[] = $this->createElement('text','name',array(
      'belongsTo'  => 'event_waiver',
      'class'      => 'form-text tx name',
      'label'      => $this->_translate->_('Title'),
      'required'   => true,
      'value'      => $this->object->name,
      'description'=> $this->_translate->_('Select a unique title for your waiver. This is how your waiver will be saved and identified within your organization.'),
      'maxlength'  => 50,
      'filters'    => array('StripTags','StringTrim',$htmlEntities,'Null'),
      'validators' => array(
        array('StringLength',null,array('max'=>50))
      )
    ));
```

My problem is if i try to type greek chars, for example 30 chars long, i will get validation error "max letter count is 50", cuz of   'maxlength'  => 50, part of code. This happens because htmlenteties filter is applied; Does anyone have idea how to override this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is...
Don't use HTML entities in a form.

Why do you want to do that?

Do it after validation, before output - but you don't need it at all.

Just be sure to use UTF-8 encoding everywhere.

Maybe read something about encodings and standards.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

If you want to prevent a user from XSS attacks (Cross-Site-Scripting), do a bad-word filter or use something like HTML Purifier.
http://htmlpurifier.org/

The encoding of HTML entities just transforms anything other then ASCII to a HTML entity. All special chars get transformed.
http://unicode.e-workers.de/entities.php

E.g. The letter β (beta) - which is a greek letter - will get transformed to `&beta;` - which is an HTML entity.

Hopefully I could help.

Good luck!

```
//Maybe like that...
$htmlEntities = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities(array(
  'doublequote'  => false,
  'quotestyle'   => ENT_NOQUOTES /*| ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML5*/
));
$elements[] = $this->createElement('text','name',array(
  'belongsTo'  => 'event_waiver',
  'class'      => 'form-text tx name',
  'label'      => $this->_translate->_('Title'),
  'required'   => true,
  'value'      => $this->object->name,
  'description'=> $this->_translate->_('Select a unique title for your waiver. This is how your waiver will be saved and identified within your organization.'),
  'maxlength'  => 50,
  'filters'    => array('StripTags','StringTrim','Null'),
  'validators' => array(
    array('StringLength',null,array('max'=>50))
  )
));

// later filter for output
$name = $htmlEntities->filter($form->getValue('name'));

//use it in your view or somewhere else
$this->view->name = $name;
```